# Jazz greats knew nothing of modes. Why are they used to improvise on standards?

Tags: jazz, modes

My understanding is before 1970, few Jazz players thought about modes. For certain, Charlie Parker, Colman Hawkins, Bud Powell, Art Tatum, Monk, etc never thought in modes.

Barry Harris shows how they did think*, a simpler, deeper way: more true to the form before Kind of Blue. Russell's Modes, inspired by a fellow patient in a tuberculosis ward, and now taught as the foundation for improvisation, seem to me a projection of Western Academic ideas unto African American idioms, with little understanding or respect to the ideas behind those idioms. Basically a "takeover" of Jazz tradition by a counterculture generation of modern Jazz players, and explainers interested in creating course curriculum. The emphasis on "Modal Theory" and scales today appears way out of porportion to it's influence in the body of recordings we now classify as Jazz.

The modal approach was used to define and frame a new form with an extreme  paucity of chords. Why is it relevant to the complex progressions which came before?

Please set me straight.

ref*  Alternative to modal approach: http://bit.ly/2GsJpBm

Comment: I think that George Russell introduced modes into jazz theory in the early '50s. Bill Evans, John Coltrane, Miles Davis, and others knew Russell, valued his work, and were inspired by it. People still teach and use other approaches to improvisation, e.g. triad-based, arpeggio-based, neighbor-tones for chromaticism. The commonly seen chord-scale theory is just one aspect of jazz improvisation that makes a good soundbite.

Comment: I think that Jamie Aebersold's play-a-long series had a lot to do with this transition, even more so than George Russell. Every volume has the same explanation of chord-scale theory, and those books have been the introduction to jazz theory for millions of people.

Comment: @Peter -- that's a good point; Aebersold, the rise of jazz clinics, the institutionalization of jazz with the advent of jazz schools like Berklee pumping out players to spread chord-scale theory. All of this really seemed to take off in the '70s and '80s.

Comment: @Kilian Froth: Respectfully, I don't think that was significant enough of an edit. A few spelling mistakes that don't change the meaning of the post at large seems very trivial. Unless not capitalising "African American" is disrespectful?

Comment: Hi - in the future, instead of the unsupportable "My understanding..", please start with, "according to [name of documented source] ...'   Pretty much the same for  " [concept] seems to me to..."

Comment: Do you mean to ask: if the mentioned jazz greats had a music school system for teaching improvisation over pre-1970 standards the way they did themselves, with what kinds of conceptual tools would they teach it? And presumably, modes would not be very high on the list of tools to know and use.

Comment: The glib answer is "so students don't need to learn functional harmony"

Answer (score 16):

> My understanding is before 1970, no Jazz players thought about modes.

This is incorrect, see this question: [How does modal jazz use chord progressions?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82760/how-does-modal-jazz-use-chord-progressions)

**A:** Modes became of interest over time as a way to organize *what pitches to use* over certain chords and sounds. This is a naturally arising phenomenon when there are many sounds to consider and memorize what notes work over each sound. Chord scales are a convenient way of organizing what notes to play over what chords, and chord scales are inherently *modes*. Naturally, musicians began to play around with these modes because they offered a different way of looking at the same notes they already knew. There was no "takeover", unless jazz musicians were trying to "take over" jazz itself and expand its lexicon with new ideas.

> Modes seem to me a projection of Western Academic ideas unto african american idioms, **with little understanding or respect to the ideas behind those idioms**. Basically a "takeover" of Jazz.

This is a projection that jazz somehow existed before ... well, before it existed. The part I highlighted is also in my estimation an egregiously bad projection that ideas somehow aren't allowed to (or simply can't) meld into one another, borrow back and forth, and so on. This is bad because **this is precisely how Jazz came about.** Jazz arose out of the musical traditions centered around New Orleans at the turn of the 20th century, which was a hot pot of everything you could imagine - namely military march music, funeral march music, dance music of the time, and music played in brothels. Remember, also, that New Orleans was a very important port city in the 1800s, meaning that much influence also came from the Caribbean and various Hispanic nations to the south. Improvisation is also nothing new even to European music: Bach, Mozart, and Beethoven were well known in their day for being able to improvise - and in the Renaissance era, improvising over a cantus firmus was an important tool for teaching counterpoint (i.e., composition). However, improvisation in the way we think of it today tends to come out of the Jazz, Blues, and Rock idioms that developed in 20th century America.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to say that students who are taught chord-scale theory and modes as a way or _the way_ to know what notes to play over everything without sounding _blatantly wrong_, lack the more essential and more true-to-the-nature-of-jazz-standards way of older traditional functional approach to harmony. Which is, I think, what Barry Harris and some other people criticize - that they didn't know anything about modes, but they could _play jazz_, and that teaching students modes without teaching the more essential traditional approach is harmful and creates bad musicians

Comment: Modes and chord scales are a tool, that's all. Don't get too hung up on them. That's the point.

Comment: This is the internet, where things are either black or white, right or wrong, good or bad, thumb up or thumb down, upvote or downvote. The OP is basically saying, "hey I found these Barry Harris videos and he's saying that modal thinking sucks, and it isn't even proper jazz, and Bud Powell and Monk didn't do it like that, so isn't it true that there's something wrong with the way jazz is taught" - and you begin by saying "this is incorrect", which can easily be interpreted as invalidating the essential idea. :)

Comment: "Towards the end of the 1950s, spurred by...George Russell, musicians began using a modal approach. They chose...to write their pieces ...using modes. Musicians employing this technique include Miles Davis, Freddie Hubbard, Bill Evans, Herbie Hancock, and Wayne Shorter." Wikipedia on Modal Jazz. None of the classic Jazz standards were written with modes as understood today. The group of musicians mentioned above created a "modern jazz". If I don't care about So What, but I love Gershwin and Arlen and Strayhorn, why would I think in modes at all?

Comment: @CharlieWebster -- "So What" _is_ a jazz standard. You are thinking of tunes from The Great American Songbook, Tin-Pan Alley tunes, and other earlier forms that were elaborated earlier in the history of jazz. If you want to play historically, don't think about modes (probably). There is nothing _wrong_ with thinking in terms of modes, although I don't know any good players who only think that way. Earlier greats, like Coleman Hawkins, thought more in terms of harmonic elaboration. Modal players came into a world interested in melodic elaboration.

Comment: @DavidBowling he is clearly talking about older standards predating So What. I think the implied question or issue is that run-of-the-mill players coming from conveyor belt schools _cannot_ play "historically" and don't even know what that is, because the only thing they've practiced is the modal approach. The answer that's perhaps being sought is, "they use the modal approach because that's the only one they know, because it's taught in schools, because teaching it fits the Western theoretical culture which fits the traditional Western assumptions for legitimate school systems". Or something.

Comment: @piiperi -- agree that he is talking about standards predating "So What." That is why I commented: Standards often refers to music that was not specific to jazz, but to songs from vaudville, tin-pan alley, showtunes, and other popular songs. On the other hand, the term Jazz Standards refers to songs that were composed as jazz which have found their way into the standard repertoire; this includes many modal tunes. OP seems to have a misunderstanding of what a jazz standard is. I know what was meant, but a correction was needed. You lost me with the rest.

Comment: Thanks so much for comments. I have edited the question to be more clear. Even the term "Standard" has evolved. When I began listening in 1980 to "The Black Cats Jump" nearly all "standards" were from what is now defined "The American Songbook". Both the music and players of the classic era moved to the back of the bus. What a rewrite! http://bit.ly/2UlCn5e

Comment: @CharlieWebster, a mode is just a scale. Do you think scales are useful or important when improvising? Pre-1950's players may not have thought about modes in the formal way that they are currently taught, but I think they did think about scales. Consider the progression | Dm7 | G7 | CΔ7 |. What's the 6th of the G7 chord? How do you conceptualize your answer to this question without thinking (to some degree) about scale steps? How do you know the 6th should be natural?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica, I'm very curious what specifically are you thinking about when you say play "historically"? Are you referring to how they *thought* about the music (e.g., Parker thought in relation to the chord tones), how they *practiced* (e.g., by playing along with recordings), or literally the licks, etc. that characterize older recordings?

Comment: @jdjazz To me it appears that my comment refers to ex nihilo's comment, which used the word "historically". If I interpret this correctly, it means old harmonic styles based on riding on and/or creating chord changes where the harmonic feeling strongly swings or leans in different directions, as opposed to vamping/staying relatively statically in a modal feeling, for a long time. Upright position, no leaning anywhere. If "So What" was based on a non-jazz pop song like many old jazz standards used to be, what kind of a song would it be? :) This discussion could be continued in the chat room.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica, thanks! I had missed ex nihilo's mention of playing historically, but you summed it up really well. Among players who didn't learn in the current institution of jazz education, this sort of criticism seems fairly common. I've usually heard it in terms of how one practices, but I never fully understood it--not because I think they're invalid, but because I've just never had a full discussion about it. Understanding the criticism in terms of the actual songs really helps me understand. There is a way in which modal tunes like So What are the antithesis of Blues for Alice

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica, maybe I'm thinking more about criticism of learning through play-alongs. It may not be fair of me to group that criticism with the criticism about modal jazz. This is where I tend to get confused on details, because I think of, e.g., the Jamey Aebersold approach as being rooted in a discussion of modes, but very heavily based on a chordal thinking. (Jamey did most of the transcriptions in the Omnibook and spent lots of time studying Charlie Parker's solos. I've always found his style to be very old school in that way.)

Comment: TY for new comments. See Carol Kaye: https://youtu.be/q4JWqK6r6N4 She also trashes modes as widely taught today. Instead it's chord tones and approach notes, and of course "the cycle". She never thinks in Dorian. See 24:48 "You have to forget these note scales...." She makes my point throughout the interview, including the fundamental nature of the three Dim chords. Modes are an inorganic artifice to explain what usually came about by much simpler thinking. IMHO.

Comment: LSM07 completely misses my point, hung up on defining "Jazz" as a term, rather than observing the evolution of the music. Tin Pan Alley tunes were critical to the explosion in the thirties...or the more chordally complex ones. The giants of the swing era, from Hawk to Parker built their skills on progressions never seen in New Orleans, and often dropped in Miles' flavor of "modern jazz". Modes only surfaced in Jazz afterward, when it was no longer popular music.